# Regular Expressions task

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Below is an example of a text file I need to parse.

`Lead Attorney: John Doe

Staff Attorneys: John Doe Jr.                                 Paralegal: John Doe III

Geographic Area: Wisconsin

Affiliated Offices: None

E-mail: blah@blah.com`

I need to parse all the key/value pairs and import it into a database.  For example, I will insert 'John Doe' into the [Lead Attorney] column.  I started a regex but I'm running into problems when parsing line 2:

`Staff Attorneys: John Doe Jr. Paralegal: John Doe III`

I started with the following regex:

`(\w*.?\w+):\s*(.)(?!(\w.?\w+:.*))`

But that does not parse out 'Staff Attorneys: John Doe Jr.' and 'Paralegal: John Doe III'.  How can I ensure that my regex returns two groups for every key/value pair even if the key/value pairs are on the same line?  Thanks!

Comment: There no way to do it, unless you assume the 2nd key is only one word. Otherwise how could we know whether the key is 'Paralegal' or 'Jr. Paralegal' ?

Comment: Do you know beforehand all of the possible keys?  In that case this would be possible using something like `(paralegal|junior paralegal|junior associate)`.

Comment: This is why I was trying to use Negative Lookahead to prevent another key from being matched '(?!(\w.?\w+:.*))'...

Comment: @amicitas, no I don't know all the possible keys beforehand.  In that example the keys are: Lead Attorney, Staff Attorneys, Paralegal, Geographic Area, Affiliated Offices and E-mail.  'John Doe III' would be imported into Paralegal.

Comment: How many lines have two instances of : in them?  Why not just parse the file, ignoring each line you are certain of, and then just spit out the list of uncertain parses so you can edit them manually, and then run it again with the fixed version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does any kind of key appear as a second key? The text above can be fixed by doing a `data.replace('Paralegal:', '\nParalegal:')` first. Then there is only one key/value pair per line, and it gets trivial:

```
>>> data = """Lead Attorney: John Doe
... Staff Attorneys: John Doe Jr. Paralegal: John Doe III
... Geographic Area: Wisconsin
... Affiliated Offices: None
... E-mail: blah@blah.com"""
>>> 
>>> result = {}
>>> data = data.replace('Paralegal:', '\nParalegal:')
>>> for line in data.splitlines():
...     key, val = line.split(':', 1)
...     result[key.strip()] = val.strip()
... 
>>> print(result)
{'Staff Attorneys': 'John Doe Jr.', 'Lead Attorney': 'John Doe', 'Paralegal': 'John Doe III', 'Affiliated Offices': 'None', 'Geographic Area': 'Wisconsin', 'E-mail': 'blah@blah.com'}
```

If "Paralegal:" also appears first you can make a regexp to do the replacement only when it's not first, or make a `.find` and check that the character before is not a newline. If there are several keywords that can appear like this, you can make a list of keywords, etc.

If the keywords can be anything, but only one word, you can look for ':' and parse backwards for space, which can be done with regexps.

If the keywords can be anything and include spaces, it's impossible to do automatically.

Comment: Lennart, sorry for the delay, but your response accomplishes my task with Python, thank you.  For learning purposes, I still have to find a way to accomplish the same (if possible) with regular expressions.  It seems to me this can be done in RegEx.  Thanks to everyone for their input!

Comment: Just because it can be done in regexps doesn't mean it should. :)